# CentOS command issue

Tags: command-line, centos

This is what I am trying to run in VMware using CentOS 5

```
/pwnat: invalid option -- p
usage: ./pwnat <-s | -c> <args>
  -c    client mode (default)
        <args>: [local ip] <local port> <proxy host> [proxy port (def:2222)] <remote host> <remote port>
  -s    server mode
        <args>: [local ip] [proxy port (def:2222)] [[allowed host]:[allowed port] ...]
  -6    use IPv6
  -v    show debug output (up to 2)
  -h    show this help and exit
./pwnat -c 3.3.3.3 -p 4444 --proxyhost IP 3.3.3.4 -proxyport 2222 --remotehost IP 8.8.8.8 --remoteport 4444
resulting in this reply 
invalid option -- p
```

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying the arguments incorrectly. If you look at the [pwnat home page](http://samy.pl/pwnat/) (or indeed actually read the help text that's displayed) you'll see that there are no `-p`, `--proxyhost`, etc. args. (These are simply supplied after the single -c option's IP address.)

There are some examples on the pwnat home page I've linked to above that should help if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get `--proxyhost` from??

The [documentation](http://samy.pl/pwnat/) gives an example:

```
./pwnat -c 8000 <pwnat.server.com> google.com 80
```

So try this:

```
./pwnat -c 4444 3.3.3.4 2222 8.8.8.8 4444
```